# What does "biased in your favour" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I checked several dictionaries and googled and checked previous *biased*-related questions here including [Is it "biased towards" or "biased against"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129399/is-it-biased-towards-or-biased-against), [Word for being biased "towards the other direction"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84463/word-for-being-biased-towards-the-other-direction), [What do you call a person who is regionally biased?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56944/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-regionally-biased) (unrelated),

Moreover, subscription-only LDOCE says:

> #### **biased (adj.)**:
>
> 1. unfairly preferring one person or group over another:
>    *Of course I'm biased, but I thought my daughter's paintings were the best.*
>    *racially biased attitudes.*
>    **biased against/towards/in favour of**
>    *news reporting that was **heavily biased** towards the government*
> 2. more interested in a particular thing than in another:
>    **biased towards**
>    *The majority of infants are biased towards being social rather than being antisocial.*

OED says:

> **biase (v.):** *To give a bias or one-sided tendency or direction to; to incline to one side; to influence, affect (often unduly or unfairly).*, 
> **biased:** Influenced; inclined in some direction; unduly or unfairly influenced; prejudiced.

But I still can't understand the meaning of the following sentence:

> I appreciate that you took the time to contact me. You are great in my opinion! But then I am very biased in your favour!

Does the sentence imply that:

a. The person saying this, is somewhat being unrealistically nice at their own expression of the addressee being great (in a negative way);
or

b. Do they mean that they're not great enough to be able to return the favor (in a positive way being keen on the addressee's greatness)?

I also notice that LDOCE uses "*favour*" rather than *favor*, which probably indicates that this usage is British only?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biased

Comment: This is general reference. The answer can easily be found (see links below)http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biased                        http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biased                                   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bias

Comment: Thank you for your links @Luis, but I don't see the meaning of *biased in favour of ...* in that link. Subscription-only LDOCE has that entry without giving a meaning to that. Also your link doesn't provide a meaning for this phrase in this context. (:

Comment: The links define "bias" and "biased".  I gather you know the meaning or "in your favour."  Therefore, you won't have any difficulty to understand what "biased in your favour" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that the speaker is acknowledging that he/she is in awe of the addressee and so might be more generous in their compliments.

Answer (score 3):

*Biased* means *prejudiced*.

You can have prejudices **against** someone or in **favour of** someone.

He is simply saying: I think you are great, *but I acknowledge I am not objective.* That's all.

Answer (score 0):

One word to define "biased in someone's favor" is **pro**.